# How to make App Shortcuts for Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have read developer guide of android developer official page and I have manage to create shortcut too. but I want to call my own activity (Explicit), instead of (Implicit) which is given in Android guide as an example. here is the URL for that https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html

I have made my code like this

ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

```
    ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this,"id1")

            .setShortLabel("Web site")
            .setLongLabel("Open the web site")


            .setIntent(new Intent(this,Shortcut.class))

    .build();
```

when I run the app I get this error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.murtaza.style2, PID: 4187
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.murtaza.style2/com.murtaza.style2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: intent's action must be set
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: intent's action must be set
                      at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:111)
                      at android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo$Builder.setIntents(ShortcutInfo.java:987)
                      at android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo$Builder.setIntent(ShortcutInfo.java:968)
                      at com.murtaza.style2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

How can I call an other activity by pressing that shortcut instead of calling any other app?

It's not 3 year old concept of putting shortcuts on home-screen its just announced with android 7.1. I want to know how to call activity by pressing that shortcut.

Comment: what do you not understand in *intent's action must be set*

Comment: Can you be more specific please ? as i want to call activity inside my app. but i am not able to do so. so please help me how can i call an other activity by .setIntent ?

Comment: This question is definately not a duplicate.

OP: You are missing your intent action;
Expand your intent and set it `.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`

Comment: This is not a duplicate! @Murtaza `.setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setClass(this, Shortcut.class))`